# LISP: Reversing a List in LISP using RPLACA/RPLACD/NCONC

Tags: lisp, land-of-lisp

So I'm trying to make a function takes in a list and reverses in place it but I'm not sure how I would use the `RPLACA`/`RPLACD`/`NONC`.  Basically does the same thing as reverse but  it uses the cons nodes of the original list and does not allocate any new cons nodes. What I have so far is

```
(defun rip(lst)
(cond   (( null lst) 0)
    ((eq (nil) (cdr (last lst))) 1)
    (((setq x (car (last lst)))
     (rplaca (car (last lst)) (car first lst))
     (rplaca (car first lst) x)) + 2 rip(butlast(rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It sounds like you have tried writing some code yourself. You should include that in the question, even if it's incomplete. It gives us a starting point and shows that you made an effort.

Comment: So far I was not using any of the required functions. 

(defun reverse-in-place (l)
  (let ((result l))
    (recurse reving ((l l) (r (reverse l))
      (cond ((not (consp l)) result)
            (else (setf   (car l) (car r))
                  (reving (cdr l) (cdr r)))))))

Comment: @John Are you sure you're using Common Lisp? I don't think either `recurse` nor`reving` are things in the language.

Comment: Sorry I added the wrong tag

Comment: @zck: RECURSE is a macro used for example in the book Land of Lisp. REVING is then a name introduced in the code snippet here.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're the same as the anonymous author of the (now deleted) [lisp in place reversing of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28554139/1281433) (the requirements are very similar:  in place reversal of a list using RPLACA/RPLACD/NONC).  If you are, I *did* miss a bit of your question in one of my comments (sorry!), but this is a *much* better formulation of the question, and includes some attempted code. A good improvement, or a new start if you're new and that wasn't your question!

Comment: I think it was a similar question but I cant see the post.  Do you happen to know what it the exact post was?  Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: @John It was this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yFJIm.png . It wasn't a good question, but the anonymous user seems to have rage-deleted the question when I (admittedly) missed something in the question.  The question content was pretty much identical though (except without code).  Is this a homework assignment?  It may have been one of your classmates. :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think it is a fellow classmate.  So far I have done the following but I'm not so sure that it is on par.  Thoughts?



(defun rip(lst)
(cond   (( null lst) 0)
        ((eq (nil) (cdr (last lst))) 1)
        (((setq x (car (last lst)))
         (rplaca (car (last lst)) (car first lst))
         (rplaca (car first lst) x)) + 2 rip(butlast(rest lst)))))

Answer (score 1):

So I believe that this was the answer they were looking for:

```
Recursive: 
(define rip (lst)
(if (null lst) nil (nconc (rip (rest lst))(rplacd lst nil))))

Non-Recursive:
(defun rip (lst)
(do ((res nil) (todo (rest lst)(rest lst)))
    ((null lst) res)
  (setf res (rplacd lst res))
  (setf lst todo) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

So a potential list argument would be `(1 2)`. We could imagine the argument is to the list with address #A and that it looks like this:

```
#A=(1 . #B)
#B=(2 . nil)
```

For each cons we create local variable storing `cdr` before setting the `cdr` to the previous `cons` which is nil for the first `cons`. When the current `cons` is `nil` your're done and the result is the previous `cons`. The result for our example would be:

```
#A=(1 . nil)
#B=(2 . #A)
```

The only mutating function you'll need would be `rplacd` since the only thing that changes are the `cdr`. The function could look something like this:

```
(defun nreverse (list)
  (labels ((aux (list prev)
             (if (endp list)
                 <??>
                 (let ((next <??>))
                   (rplacd <??> <??>)
                   (aux <??> <??>)))))
    (aux list nil)))
```

Or if you don't mind leaking you can do this:

```
(defun nreverse (list &optional prev)
  (if (endp list)
      <??>
      (let ((next <??>))
        (rplacd <??> <??>)
        (nreverse <??> <??>))))
```